# Custom code for WordPress dynamic menu

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, menus, navigation

Without using plugins, how can I create a custom WordPress navigation menu to produce the following code?

```
<div class="bottom_section_full">
    <div class="bottom_section_left bottom_part">
        <a href="what.html"><img src="images/cont1.png" alt="cont1"/></a>
        <a href="what.html"><img src="images/border.png" alt="border" class="border"/></a>
        <a href="what.html"><p>What We Do</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_section_top bottom_part" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <a href="what.html"><img src="images/cont2.png" alt="cont2"/></a>
        <a href="what.html"><img src="images/border.png" alt="border" class="border"/></a>
        <a href="what.html"><p>What We Do</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_section_bottom bottom_part">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/cont3.png" alt="cont3"/></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/border.png" alt="border" class="border"/></a>
        <a href="#"><p>What We Do</p></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For `class="bottom_section_full"` I want to use `ul`, and for `class="bottom_part"` 
I want to use `li`.

I also want to use a field for images.

Is possible to build a dynamic menu like this in WordPress?

Comment: Probably, what have you tried?

Comment: I am really sorry i don't try anything. As far as i work with only with <ul> and <li> tag. And i really confused what i should use.
What type of functionality i use :(

Comment: You need to search this site, the internet in general, and the WordPress Codex for "wp_nav_menu"